# Changing image immediately

Tags: java, image, swing, replace, jpanel

I am currently trying to learn a little bit about programming games.
I got myself a player class extending a sprite class i wrote by myself.
Now i want to know, how i can change the image of my player object in the middle of the running game. imagine a spaceship, when pressing the right arrow key it should be a different image, inclined to the right.
now i am trying to do this:
when a button is pressed (e.g. space) setImage(the new image)
But now, when i call this method my image just disappears and the new one won't appear?

Any ideas?
My code of the Main class:

```
    public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public boolean isRunning;

    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;

    private Player player;

    public Game() {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        init();
        while(isRunning) {

            update();
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        player = new Player("/ship_blue", WIDTH - 32/2, 400);
    }

    public void update() {
        player.update();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        drawPlayer(g2d);
    }

    public void drawPlayer(Graphics2D g2d) {
        if(player.isVisible)g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(),(int) player.getX(), (int) player.getY(), null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game gameComponent = new Game();
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Invaders");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(size);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(gameComponent);
    }

    public class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the main class, now the player class in which i am trying to change the image in the onPress() method:

```
    public class Player extends Sprite{

    private double glideSpeed = .125;
    private int fixY;
    private int xDirection = 0;
    private int yDirection = 1;

    public Player(String source, int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(source));
        setImage(ii.getImage());
        setTileSize(ii.getIconWidth());
        setSpeed(0.2);
        fixY = y;
    }

    public void update() {
        x += xDirection * 1.4;
        glide(10);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            xDirection = 1;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            xDirection = -1;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            ImageIcon ii2 = new ImageIcon("/player_blue_negativ");
            setImage(ii2.getImage()); //<-----Here I am trying to change the image
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            xDirection = 0;
        }
    }

    public void glide(int span) {
        y += yDirection * glideSpeed;
        if(y - fixY > span || fixY - y > span) {
            yDirection = -yDirection;
        }
    }
}
```

And to complete everything here's my sprite class:

```
    public class Sprite {

    protected double x;
    protected double y;
    protected int tileSize;
    protected double speed;
    protected Image img;
    protected boolean isVisible;

    public Sprite() {
        isVisible = true;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getTileSize() {
        return tileSize;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return img;
    }

    public boolean getVisible() {
        return isVisible;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setTileSize(int tileSize) {
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
    }

    public void setImage(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void die() {
        isVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    ImageIcon ii2 = new ImageIcon("/player_blue_negativ");
```

There is the basic problem.  All images should be loaded and cached prior to an event happening.  When the event occurs, use the cached image and the GUI should render immediately.

As [mentioned by @camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18292215/418556), the use of an `ImageIcon` also subtly slips from an `URL` to a `String` (presumed to represent a 
`File` path).  Stick with the `URL` obtained from `getResource(..)`.

### On `ImageObserver`.

If an `ImageObserver` is used to paint the image, the observer will be informed of updates to images that are asynchronously loaded.  All components (e.g. `JPanel`) implement `ImageObserver`, so..

```
g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(),(int) player.getX(), (int) player.getY(), null);
```

Should be:

```
g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(),(int) player.getX(), (int) player.getY(), this);
```

### Free the EDT!

```
class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable ..

Thread.sleep(5);
```

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. 
Also don't attempt to update the GUI from anything other than the EDT.

Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` in a `Runnable`, implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

### Use `paintComponent(Graphics)` for Swing components!

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
```

Should be:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Comment: When using the ImageObserver the image still just disappears... So the ImageObserver didn't change anything, I guess?

Comment: runnable together with paint() cound't be works properly in Java7, this code is designated to Java4/5 versions

Answer (score 2):

When you load the initial image you use the following without a problem:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(source));
```

When you change the image you use:

```
ImageIcon ii2 = new ImageIcon("/player_blue_negativ");
```

I'm guessing you don't find the image, probably because you don't need the "/". But why not use the same method that you know works?